# Loop for shape calculator

Tags: python, loops

I need to add a loop to the code in order to allow the user to restart the programme and choose another of the available shapes.

```
import math
import time
shapearea = 0
pi = 3.14159
print("Select shape\n1.Square\n2.Circle\n3.Triangle")
shape = input("Enter shape(Square/Circle/Triangle):")
if shape == "square":
     sideval = int(input("Enter side value of the shape:"))
     print("Calculating...")
     #time.sleep(2)
     shapearea = shapearea +(sideval ** 2)
elif shape == "circle":
     circleradius = int(input("Enter radius value of the circle:"))
     print("Calculating...")
     #time.sleep(2)
     shapearea = shapearea +(pi * circleradius **2)
elif shape == "triangle":
    height = int(input("Enter the height of the shape:"))
    base = int(input("Enter the base of the shape:"))
    print("Calculating...")
    #time.sleep(2)
    shapearea = shapearea +(base*height/2)
else:
     print("The given shape is invalid, give a valid shape to calculate the area")
print ("The area of the chosen shape is " "%.2f" % shapearea)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: wrap the code in a `while True:`... Don't forget to add an option to exit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. This isn't a question. Please [edit] to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I tried using the while function, but I haven't done a loop before and i'm not sure how to approach this

Comment: So try searching online and do some tutorials about loops. It is very basic and shouldn't be hard to understand or find materials about online...

Comment: Use `while ... break`

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe this could help you:

```
import math
import time

def calculate():
    shapearea = 0
    pi = 3.14159
    print("Select shape\n1.Square\n2.Circle\n3.Triangle")
    shape = input("Enter shape(Square/Circle/Triangle):")
    if shape == "square":
         sideval = int(input("Enter side value of the shape:"))
         print("Calculating...")
         #time.sleep(2)
         shapearea = shapearea +(sideval ** 2)
    elif shape == "circle":
         circleradius = int(input("Enter radius value of the circle:"))
         print("Calculating...")
         #time.sleep(2)
         shapearea = shapearea +(pi * circleradius **2)
    elif shape == "triangle":
        height = int(input("Enter the height of the shape:"))
        base = int(input("Enter the base of the shape:"))
        print("Calculating...")
        #time.sleep(2)
        shapearea = shapearea +(base*height/2)
    else:
         print("The given shape is invalid, give a valid shape to calculate the area")
    print ("The area of the chosen shape is " "%.2f" % shapearea)

calculate()

while input("Do you want to continue?(Y/N)") == "Y":
    calculate()
print("exiting from program...")
```